# Url in path param

Tags: java, jax-rs

in jax-rs is it possible to send path param like this "http://localhost:8080/"?

I mean there is no problem when I want to send path param like "1" or "6". But how can I send this? "http://localhost:8080/"

@Edit

For example I've path like this:

```
/api/media/{url}
```

and I want to transfer http://localhost:8080/ under {url}

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to provide way more input on the actual situation and your intend.

Comment: One option is to escape it.

Comment: That is ok for server side. {url} like any other path parameter. Just you need put url-encode properly when test, or write client to consume service.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it by encoding all special characters using percent encoding. Recommended way is to pass as query parameter with percentage encoding